# Monit XMPP notifications

Tags: monitoring, xmpp, monit

Is there any way to tell Monit to send XMPP notifications as well as emails on alerts?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Monit, but if you can specify an arbitrary command, you could setup a python script that sends a message via DBus to either Pidgin or Finch. Pidgin/Finch should already be running and be connected.

Here is an example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dbus, gobject, dbus.glib
import sys

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
obj = bus.get_object("im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService", "/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject")
purple = dbus.Interface(obj, "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface")

account = purple.PurpleAccountsFindAny('sender@gmail.com/Home', 'prpl-jabber')
conv = purple.PurpleConversationNew(1, account, 'recipient@gmail.com')
im = purple.PurpleConvIm(conv)
purple.PurpleConvImSend(im, sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's one possibility. I could use one of my Ruby scripts for this purpose.

Comment: @MilanNovota How did you manage to provide an arbitrary command?

Answer (score 2):

Monit uses emails to send notifications. I don't know if a xmpp notification is provided, but you could use or code an email to xmpp gateway ?

I just found this : [http://invalidlogic.com/code/smtp-to-xmpp-gateway-in-ruby/] I don't know if it works, but it's an interesting solution to get email notifications (not only monit ones) onto your favorite xmpp client.

Comment: Well, that's an interesting option. Thanks!